# How to know, who makes GUI sticky?

Tags: windows-10, performance, freeze, gui

Sometimes, my `GUI` becomes sticky. I many applications scrolling and typing occurs with unexplainable pauses.

How to know, which application does this?

May be keyboard switched, screenshot taker, adblocker (in browser)?

CPU load is low.

Comment: Are you talking about lag? GUI sticky is not an ICT term and therefor, I have no idea what you mean. If it is indeed lag, then you need to scan for malware and virusses.

Comment: I don't know what are correct terms. I described what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the task manager or the resource monitor and look for other things apart from CPU (mainly memory and disk).

I bet the issue is related with disk usage (maybe you're running out of memory and you're using the swap file or maybe windows updates are running in the background).